# How to get the "TimeToLive" property of a group member?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I made a small program to add a user to a group for a while. I want to display the users of the group in the DataGridView. I want to know when the user leaves the group. I can find this out from powershell.

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity "UG_TS_CISCO" -Properties members -ShowMemberTimeToLive
****************
Members           : {<TTL=204236>,CN=Ilya Evseev,***, <TTL=31412>,CN=Vasyan Pupkin,***}
```

```
DirectoryEntry dc = new DirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher searcher= new DirectorySearcher(dc);
searcher.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=UG_TS_CISCO))");

foreach (SearchResult src in searcher.FindAll()) {
    DirectoryEntry groupEntry = src.GetDirectoryEntry();
    object members = groupEntry.Invoke("members", null);

    foreach (object groupMember in (IEnumerable)members)
    {
        DirectoryEntry member = new DirectoryEntry(groupMember);
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(member.Properties["name"][0], member.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]);

    }
}
```

But how to get this data from the application using DirectoryServices I can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.dsinternals.com/en/how-the-active-directory-expiring-links-feature-really-works/#creating-expiring-links-using-ldap), you need to perform the search with the [`LDAP_SERVER_LINK_TTL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f4f523a8-abc0-4b3a-a471-6b2fef135481) LDAP extended control. I don't think `DirectorySearcher` allows you to add any extended controls manually.

You may have to resort to using [`LdapConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection?view=netframework-4.8.1) and [`SearchRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchrequest?view=netframework-4.8.1).

There's an example of how to use that in their [Introduction to System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb332056(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#sdspintro_topic5_simplesearch) article.

To add that extended control, I think this should work (untested):

```
searchRequest.Controls.Add(new DirectoryControl("1.2.840.113556.1.4.2309", null, false, true));
```